# How skip value if the result minus? in excel

Tags: excel

I want show up string from table use vlook up, but when the value has not been entered then the table is empty, but in the cell he has filled in the value = -4, can this be resolved?

my formula `=VLOOKUP(MOD((U2-4);12);sio;2)`

[table_aray sio and output valu = -4 (block yellow = 'monyet')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plp09.png)

Comment: please tell me what is the range `sio` address ? I will write the Index Match formula instead to solve the problem.

Comment: sio is a table array, 2 coloumn, first is a int, second column are string

Comment: can you show a screenshot from this table that returns value -4 ?

Comment: i just upload.. please check this, i hope u can help me @SharifLotfi

Comment: vlookup parameters should be splited  by comma, not semi-comma;  meanwhile  you should add comma , after 2

Comment: I still don't understand, can you take an example? @Anabas

Comment: @Anabas It depends on OS Region & Language Settings, both of them can be right

Comment: @Oktaviana your screenshot is not clear, column U was not shown. and try show the cell witch returns value -4 , show formula bar with formula init.

Comment: you can send me the file , I will send back solution here with screen shot for all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about your data region, maybe something like this

```
=if(isblank(U2),"",VLOOKUP(MOD((U2-4),12),sio,2,0)
```